# This is some errors when I use command line to install custom plugin-in

Tags: cordova, command-line

I use phonegap3.1.0 command line to create a new project and add a custom plugin. This custom plugin works well. When I use command line to uninstall this plugin and reinstall it, this error occurs:

```
2013-10-10 15:48:33.059 EmailPlugin[2382:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-10-10 15:48:33.435 EmailPlugin[2382:907] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-10-10 15:48:33.766 EmailPlugin[2382:907] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/850B3B6C-1BA0-49A6-AFD2-475963AF80DB/EmailPlugin.app/www/index.html
2013-10-10 15:48:36.962 EmailPlugin[2382:907] CDVPlugin class Dialer (pluginName: Dialer) does not exist.
2013-10-10 15:48:36.964 EmailPlugin[2382:907] ERROR: Plugin 'Dialer' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-10-10 15:48:36.966 EmailPlugin[2382:907] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 117] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "INVALID",
  "Dialer",
  "call",
  [
    "01088896667"
  ]
]
```

This is config.xml:

```
 <feature name="Dialer">
     <param name="ios-package" value="Dialer" />
 </feature>
```

I have checked config.xml and plugin files,they are good. I don't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Something may be wrong with the ios.json file in the plugins folder. Often times my issues were fixed by deleting (or renaming) the file and rebuilding since PhoneGap generates it every time.